# Codeigniter session authentification still allows restricted page to load

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to restrict access from a page if the user is not logged in. The weird thing is that the webpage, when tried to be accessed by an unauthorised user, shows the page for the restricted access (with the "unauthorised, please login" message and, on the same page, it loads the members only page).

For the site controller:

```
class Site extends CI_Controller {

function __construct(){

    parent::__construct();

    $isLogged=$this->session->userdata('logged');
    if($isLogged!='logged' || !isset($isLogged)){

        $data['content']='denied';
        $this->load->view('include/template', $data);

    }


}

function members(){

        $data['content']='memberArea';
        $this->load->view('include/template', $data);

}
```

The login form :

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {


function index () {

    $data['content']='loginForm';
    $this->load->view('include/template', $data);  
}


function validateMember(){

    // load the model for the login authentification
    $this->load->model('loginModel');
    //query should also contain the user details 
    $query = $this->loginModel->authenticate();

    //if it returns something:
    if($query){

        foreach ($query as $row){

            //set user data to be passed    
            $details=array(
            'username'=>$row->user_name,
            'id'=>$row->id,
            'logged'=>'logged',);

        }

    //set session
    $this->session->set_userdata($details); 

    redirect('site/members');

    }

    else{

        $this->index(); 
    }


}
```

The model for the login is:

```
class LoginModel extends CI_Model {

function authenticate(){

//select active fields
$this->db->select('id, user_name, password');    
// query to select from table where conditions
$query = $this->db->get_where('login', array(
            'user_name'=>$this->input->post('username'),
            'password'=>$this->input->post('password'),), 
                    1);

    //if it finds something...must ask if i need to manually close the database with $this->db->close();
    if($query->num_rows()==1){

        foreach($query->result() as $row){

            $data[]=$row; 
        }

        return $data;
    }

    else {return false;}
}
```

}

My tests showed that site continues to call the other functions even if the construct function fails. the session does contain the data. If i use die() or exit() the webpages loads blank. many thanks in advance!

PS: the views only have `<p>` in them, nothing fancy.

Comment: Hi, if you want to add your own answer, please do - but do so in the answer box, rather than as an update to a question. Rather than adding 'solved' to the title, tick the answer you most prefer (even your own if you like). I've rolled the question back to the previous version, but you can [copy your edit from here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15599079/revisions).

Comment: oh sorry.i will then select the answer i most prefer. no offence intended guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two solutions to this problem.

1. Redirect to another page that doesn't check for authentication. You can use `redirect(<url>);` from the URL helper.
2. Use `exit()` in the `__construct()` with the buffered output flushed.  When you call `$this->load->view()` the data is sent to a buffer called `output` in CodeIgniter.  You can write that buffer by doing :

   ```
   if($isLogged!='logged' || !isset($isLogged)){

       $data['content']='denied';
       $this->load->view('include/template', $data);

       // Write the output.
       echo $this->output->get_output();  

       // Stop the execution of the script.
       exit();
   }
   ```

   or you can by-pass the output buffer with:

   ```
   if($isLogged!='logged' || !isset($isLogged)){

       $data['content']='denied';          

       // Writes the content instead of sending it to the buffer.  
       echo $this->load->view('include/template', $data, true);  

       // Stop the execution of the script.
       exit();
   }
   ```

Pick which ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor method does not "fail", the if statement is simply executed (because the condition is true) and there is no reason why this would prevent other methods from being executed.

Inside the constructor method, at the end of the `if` block, you may insert  an `exit` statement, this way the page would probably behave as you are expecting.

See here http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php

Comment: well, the if statement gets executed, as it loads the restricted access page content. it simply continues to load the other page as well ...

Comment: Yes sorry you are right, however the problem is still that you are not preventing the other methods to be executed alongside the constructor, you need an exit statement, now I edit my answer.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, but as i already said, i tried placing a die or exit or return or break statement in the if to stop execution of the other methods. the thing is i dont quite understand why if the construct method redirects to a page it continues to load the other page. in the same page. as if the constructor method concatentates the two functions. it is quite weird!

Comment: Because it is a constructor, it is executed whenever you create an instance, it does not prevent other methods to be executed, watch this video, start watching from 7'30" http://tutorialcodeigniter.com/beginners/creating-controller.html

Comment: Many thanks, i will watch this. short update: it seems if i use the redirect, it redirects me to the login page. perhaps the answer is that the redirect script should be located in another controller. i will update after i will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

You're testing if there is a query, not if the query actually return anything. Check the num rows and make sure they equal 1, doing greater than 0 is bad practice on login checks.

```
if($query->num_rows==1){
```

PS. Post your model code as well, it's possible the error is there and it's returning a result even when it shouldn't.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but the num_rows is checked in the model before passing the data to the controller. i cannot check it in the controller as it says non object.